# How to override major mode bindings

Tags: key-bindings, major-mode, keymap, minor-mode

Sometimes my global keybindings are overridden by a major mode.  An easy example is the following setting in my init file

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-j") 'newline-and-indent)
```

But annoyingly this keybinding is hidden by the "Lisp Interaction" major mode which is the default mode of the scratch buffer.

**When I find myself in a situation where a major mode (or minor mode) is hiding my global keybinding, how can I get it back?**

Note: My question is not *"How can I bind `C-j` to `newline-and-indent` in "Lisp Interaction" mode?"*  I am interested in a much more general answer about how to deal with keymaps that clash or user keybindings that get hidden by some major/minor mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is a "shortcut" approach too for the same solution if you don't want to define your own minor mode (that I talk about in my first answer).

You can install the [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) package available from Melpa and make use of `bind-key*` or `bind-keys*` macro that's part of the `bind-key` package that ships with `use-package`.

From the documentation of [`bind-key.el`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/bind-key.el):

```el
;; If you want the keybinding to override all minor modes that may also bind
;; the same key, use the `bind-key*' form:
;;
;;   (bind-key* "<C-return>" 'other-window)

;; To bind multiple keys in a `bind-key*' way (to be sure that your bindings
;; will not be overridden by other modes), you may use `bind-keys*' macro:
;;
;;    (bind-keys*
;;     ("C-o" . other-window)
;;     ("C-M-n" . forward-page)
;;     ("C-M-p" . backward-page))
```

Comment: In case anyone is curious, note that this just uses a minor mode behind the scenes. It does take a different approach to conflicts with other minor modes, by using `emulation-mode-map-alists` to enforce precedence).

Comment: I have marked this as the answer because of its simplicity.  It is essentially doing the same thing as [this answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/358/93), but it is conveniently doing most of the work for you behind the scenes.

Comment: @nispio You're correct. From my experience the only difference is the method that's used to make the minor mode bindings override other modes globally. But the advantage of the other approach (of having your own minor mode) is that you can turn it off momentarily to try out the original emacs bindings if you ever need to ( I have needed to do that a few times).

Comment: Add `(bind-key* "C-M-&" 'override-global-mode)`, to your init, and you can usually get the bindings out of your way quick if you need to.  Since `override-global-mode` is not a "global" minor mode, you will still need to deactivate it on a per-buffer basis.  So if you find yourself frequently deactivating the global override keys then this solution is not convenient.

Comment: Strangely, nothing I do seems to prevent Magit from overriding my global keybinding for C-return.  In many contexts it works, but if for example my cursor is sitting on a diff hunk, Magit takes over.

Comment: …and it turns out that if you really want to override everything, you need to  to use `overriding-terminal-local-map` instead, per https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-Keymaps.html

Unfortunately I haven't yet figured out what that code looks like.

Answer (score 41):

You can define your own minor mode and its key map and have that override all other modes (minor + major). That's exactly why I chose to write my own minor mode.

Steps to have your key bindings override all bindings:

- Defining your own minor mode and key map as shown below.
- Activate your minor mode globally
- `(define-key my-mode-map (kbd "C-j") #'newline-and-indent)`

Similarly your other key bindings set in your minor mode will override those in other modes.

I highly recommend reading the [blog post](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2013/02/06/) by Christopher Wellons on how to write a minor mode. That blog plus the annoyance of having to set multiple key bindings to `nil` in multiple major and minor modes inspired me to write my own minor mode.

The best part of using this approach is that when you want to check what the key bindings do in emacs' default configuration, you simply turn off your minor mode; you then turn it back on and you get back your custom key bindings.

```el
;; Main use is to have my key bindings have the highest priority
;; https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/elisp/modi-mode.el

(defvar my-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap)
  "Keymap for `my-mode'.")

;;;###autoload
(define-minor-mode my-mode
  "A minor mode so that my key settings override annoying major modes."
  ;; If init-value is not set to t, this mode does not get enabled in
  ;; `fundamental-mode' buffers even after doing \"(global-my-mode 1)\".
  ;; More info: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/16693/115
  :init-value t
  :lighter " my-mode"
  :keymap my-mode-map)

;;;###autoload
(define-globalized-minor-mode global-my-mode my-mode my-mode)

;; https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/bind-key.el
;; The keymaps in `emulation-mode-map-alists' take precedence over
;; `minor-mode-map-alist'
(add-to-list 'emulation-mode-map-alists `((my-mode . ,my-mode-map)))

;; Turn off the minor mode in the minibuffer
(defun turn-off-my-mode ()
  "Turn off my-mode."
  (my-mode -1))
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook #'turn-off-my-mode)

(provide 'my-mode)

;; Minor mode tutorial: http://nullprogram.com/blog/2013/02/06/
```

Answer (score 5):

To have a global binding override a major mode binding, simply set the binding to `nil` in the major mode:

```
(define-key my-major-mode-map (kbd "C-j") nil)
```

It's not possible to have the global binding take precedence over all modes in general (otherwise there would be no point in having major modes), but you could hack around it by creating your own minor mode with your most important bindings. Then you would at least have precedence over most (although not necessarily all) modes.

Comment: Will this work for any arbitrary major mode?  In other words, if I install a major mode called "foo-mode" I can put `(define-key foo-mode (kbd "C-j") nil)` in my .emacs file and expect this to work?

Comment: Actually you'll want it to be `foo-mode-map` (my example in the answer was bad), but yes, that will disable the keybinding in the major mode so the global keybinding will be used instead (unless there's a different minor mode that's using it).

Comment: Is it fairly universal that the keymap for `foo-mode` will be called `foo-mode-map`?

Comment: @nispio yes, that's true for the vast majority of modes (although there are a few rogues out there).

Answer (score 1):

You can use these macros:

```
(defmacro expose-global-keybinding (binding map)
  `(define-key ,map ,binding (lookup-key (current-global-map) ,binding)))

(defmacro expose-bindings (map bindings)
  `(dolist (bnd ,bindings)
     (expose-global-keybinding (kbd bnd) ,map)))
```

**EDIT**:

Check the example bellow:

If the keymap X is overriding your global binding Y, you write:

`(expose-bindings X '("Y"))`

And then the override will be 'undone'.

Comment: your macro you benefit from using the backquote: `(define-key ,map ,binding (lookup-key (current-global-map) ,binding))

Comment: Can you comment on what the macro is doing, and how to use it? It is not clear to me from the code.

Comment: The first macro just looks-up the key in the global map and assign the result to the `other map`, thus, exposing the global map binding through the `other map`. The second one just lets you apply the former for a list of bindings.

Comment: Sorry if I am being dense, but I still don't completely understand the usage.  Do I need to define my own special global keymap? Does it need to belong to a minor mode?  Do I perform `expose-bindings` first, and then globally bind those keys to the commands that I want?  Maybe you could show an example of what I might put in my init file to make this work.

Comment: You don't need to define nothing special.

Comment: If your minor mode X overrides some binding from the global-map, say C-h, using `expose-global-keybinding` will 'undo' this override.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you have still not made the usage clear.  Can you just assume for a moment that I don't know how to read a defmacro and give me *an example* of how to use it?  So far, the code you have provided gives me an error: `Symbol's value as variable is void: better-registers-map`.  I'm guessing that I need to *define something special*.

Comment: I have edited my answer. See if you can understand it better now.

Comment: Note that these macro names are misnomers. They do not "expose" the global binding, but rather they *duplicate* the global binding. If the real global binding changes, these duplicate copies will not.

Answer (score 1):

Just redefine it after loading main file:

```
(with-eval-after-load "majormodeel"                                            
  (define-key major-mode-map*(kbd "C-j") 'newline-and-indent))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this requires an explicit entry for every mode whose map has a binding for `C-j`, which is one of the things I wanted to avoid.  Also, I think unbinding the key by setting it to `nil` in the major-mode map (as suggested in the answer by @shosti) is probably preferable here. Not downvoting, because the `with-eval-after-load` adds something new to the existing answers, at least.

Comment: Correct your question in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, packages like Magit will override even `emulation-mode-map-alists` (and thus `bind-key*`).  If you really want to take precedence, this appears to be the only way:

```
(unless overriding-terminal-local-map
  (setq overriding-terminal-local-map (make-sparse-keymap)))

(define-key overriding-terminal-local-map [(control return)] 'other-window)
```

**However,** something I do not yet understand occasionally sets `overriding-terminal-local-map` to `nil`.  So I am currently using a combination of this technique and `bind-key*`.