# Global key binding overriden by undo-tree

Tags: key-bindings, undo-tree-mode

I am trying to remap globally `C-/` but the `undo-tree` package hinders me from doing so. When calling this command (in my init file):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-/") 'left-char)
```

*after* having loaded `undo-tree` (of course), the binding still refers to the undo command.

Any ideas on how to override `undo-tree`'s pervasiveness?

Comment: Related: [How to override major mode bindings](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/352/115)

Comment: @kaushalmodi: +1 - My crystal ball tells me that's probably all that is involved here.

Comment: @kaushalmodi Thanks. That was the solution. If you pose it as such, I will be glad to approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solution can be achieved in one of the two ways:

- You define your own minor mode whose key-bindings overrides the bindings set by all other minor/major modes.
- You set that particular key-binding in that minor/major mode to `nil`.

These solutions can be implemented in multiple ways and they have been presented in detail in these Emacs SE and SO posts:

- Emacs SE Question: [How to override major mode bindings](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/352/115)

  - My preferred solution is to have [my own minor-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/358/115) so that I have full control of enabling/disabling the overrides done by my minor mode. By default I set all the key-bindings in my minor mode key map. I do `global-set-key` only for the bindings that I want to be overriden (very few cases).
- SO Question: [Globally override key binding in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/683425/1219634)

Comment: Thanks. I use the `bind-key.el` solution, as directly creating a minor mode seemed too difficult.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this, if you want to remap *all* keys bound to `undo-tree-undo`.

```
 (global-set-key [remap undo-tree-undo] 'left-char)
```

You can also try making your binding in `undo-tree-mode-map`, assuming that is what is used by `undo-tree-mode`:

```
(add-hook 'undo-tree-mode-hook
          (lambda () (define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "C-/") 'left-char)))
```

(Usually there is a keymap `[mode-name]-map` like `undo-tree-mode-map`. In this case the name is actually `undo-tree-map`.)

Comment: Thanks. But I really not want either to lose all other bindings to the undo command, or to map them to my other command.

Comment: Do you need the hook?  Or could you just modify the map once and for all?

Comment: @nispio: You don't need the hook if the library has already been loaded. If it has not been loaded then presumably `undo-tree-mode-map` is not yet defined (unbound variable).

Comment: @NVaughan: That's why I mentioned the second possibility: just bind that one key, `C-/`, and only do so on `undo-tree-mode-map`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using Emacs under terminal? Check `C-h k C-/` to see what it is.

In my case, when pressing `C-/` in terminal, it actually invokes `C-_`.

Comment: Not using it on terminal. And I get the following: "C-/ runs the command undo-tree-undo, which is an interactive compiled
Lisp function in `undo-tree.el'.

It is bound to C-_, C-/, C-z, <menu-bar> <edit> <undo>, <undo>."