# Disable org-mode keyboard shortcuts

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

Is there a simple way (e.g. customization option) to disable some of `org-mode`'s keyboard shortcuts? I normally use shift-right_arrow or shift-left_arrow to select text (expand region), but in `org-mode` this combination serves to promote/demote heading.

(Yes, I know there's an emacsen way of marking and expanding the region, but I was wondering if there's and out-of-the-box way of disabling this feature in `org-mode`...)

Comment: You can also choose to override any mode's bindings with yours: [Related emacs SE question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/352/115)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking to disable those keys permanently for org-mode? You can do that by unsetting the keys in `org-mode-map`.

For example, add the following to your emacs init file:

```
(eval-after-load 'org
  (progn
    (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<S-right>") nil)
    (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<S-left>") nil)))
```

When org mode is loaded this removes the org-local bindings for shift-right and left. That way the global bindings will work in org files.

Comment: In case you get `Symbol's value as variable is void: org-mode-map` make sure to `(require 'org)` first.