# How to disable org-metaleft in org capture?

Tags: org-mode

The combination of org capture, `org-metaleft` (bound to `S-LEFT`), and refiling can mess up an org file. Here is an example:

- Start a new heading with quick capture, say `*** new`. This heading is refiled depending on your quick capture template, say `** Miscellaneous`.
- Press `S-LEFT` twice, which is bound to `org-metaleft` and which I often use to go back a word instead of `M-b`. The heading `*** new` becomes `* new` and all the next level 2 headings will become children of this new heading.
- Refile with `C-c C-w`, say to `* Today`. The heading becomes `** new` and carries all the children with it to the new location.

The problem with this behavior is that it is completely hidden, unlike in the main buffer where I would see it happening. So I think `org-metaleft` should be disabled in org capture.

Why is it enabled, and how to turn it off?

Comment: I don't use a current version of `org-mode` and do not anticipate installing it any time soon.  That being said, a quick Google search lead me to the variable `org-capture-mode-map` which contains a doc-string:  "*Keymap for `org-capture-mode`, a minor mode.  Use this map to set additional keybindings for when Org-mode is used for a capture buffer.*"  So, perhaps you can just define the key has having a `nil` value for the function ...  See:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7546/disable-org-mode-keyboard-shortcuts  You may need to `(require 'org-capture)` or use `eval-after-load` ...

Comment: @lawlist I'm curious if you use another software to organize your to-do list and track time?

Comment: I use a flat text file for each client to track time using a certain format that is always the same so that I can use a regexp to calculate all of the time spent over a given period; e.g.,  `0.2 hours -- 12/17/2019:  Conference with client.`  I manually log my time in/out.  For the past 5+ years, I have strictly used a custom/modified version of `org-mode` to keep track of tasks and events, using the same keywords as `toodledo.com`, which I sync with using a custom/modified of `org-toodledo.el`.  I use a custom/modified version of `calfw`; *and*, https://github.com/lawlist/lorg-calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @lawlist's comments, `C-h k <M-LEFT>` on an org-capture buffer shows that the key is bound through `org-mode-map`. I overrode the keybinding of `M-LEFT` to a function that checks if the current buffer is an Org-capture buffer:

```lisp
(defun my-org-is-buffer-org-capture()
  "Checks if the current buffer is an org-capture buffer."
  (string-match-p (regexp-quote "CAPTURE-") (buffer-name)))

(defun my-org-metaleft (&optional arg)
  "Wrapper function for org-metaleft, except in org-capture buffers where it calls backward-word."
  (interactive)
  (if (my-org-is-buffer-org-capture)
      (backward-word)
    (org-metaleft arg)))

(defun my-org-metaright (&optional arg)
  "Wrapper function for org-metaright, except in org-capture buffers where it calls forward-word."
  (interactive)
  (if (is-buffer-org-capture)
      (forward-word)
    (org-metaright arg)))

;; Disable org-metaleft and org-metaright in org-capture buffers
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-left>") 'my-org-metaleft)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-right>") 'my-org-metaright)
```