# AceJump key bindings not working in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

My `ace-jump-mode` bindings don't seem to work when I'm editing in `org-mode`.
This is how I define them in my [.emacs](https://github.com/mperdikeas/environment/blob/master/.emacs).

```
(progn
  (require 'ace-jump-mode)                                                                                                                                                            
    (define-key global-map (kbd "C-c SPC") 'ace-jump-mode)                                                                                                                            
    (define-key global-map (kbd "C-c C-c SPC") 'ace-jump-char-mode)                                                                                                                   
    (define-key global-map (kbd "C-c C-c C-c SPC") 'ace-jump-line-mode)                                                                                                               
)
```

Instead, when editing in `org-mode`, `C-c SPC` gives on the mini-buffer:

```
Not in table data field
```

... with the other bindings also failing (in different ways). I would prefer to disable these bindings from the `org-mode` commands they are bound to as I don't use them (for the time being at least).

If that's not possible, is it possible to instead only define alternative bindings for the `ace-jump` commands only when working in `org-mode`?

In general what is the "proper" way of addressing such clashes?

Comment: FYI: An alternative to `(define-key global-map...)` is `(global-set-key...)`.

Comment: Major modes should not be redefining the `C-c SPC` keybinding, as this is reserved for minor modes. If the org-mode major mode is redefining it, it is a bug of that mode.

Comment: @Tyler Why would you consider `C-c SPC` to be reserved for minor modes? `C-c` is a common prefix to use for mode-specific commands,and the Emacs info node on "Major Modes" mentions this. (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Major-Modes.html)

Comment: Answering my own question above. The Emacs Lisp manual says:  "The key sequences bound in a major mode keymap should usually start with ‘C-c’, followed by a control character, a digit, or ‘{’, ‘}’, ‘<’, ‘>’, ‘:’ or ‘;’.  The other punctuation characters are reserved for minor modes, and ordinary letters are reserved for users."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Global map keys get overridden by major-mode and minor-mode keymaps.

There are a couple of ways to solve the problem specific to your case:

1. Do not bind `ace-jump-mode` to  `C-c SPC`. Instead bind it to something else that does not clash like `C-c C-SPC`.

   **Many might recommend using this approach.** *If you use `org-mode` frequently, or might start using it frequently in future, you do not want your personal bindings clashing with the org-mode bindings :)*.
2. As the `C-c SPC` in `org-mode-map` is overriding your binding in the `global-map`, you can bind that particular key in `org-mode-map` to `nil`. See [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/353/115).

   ```el
   (with-eval-after-load 'org
       (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c SPC") nil))
   ```
3. Do not bind `ace-jump-mode` in `global-map` but [in your own minor-mode map](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/358/115) or using something like [`use-package` package's `bind-key*` or `bind-keys*` macro](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/360/115).

---

Above links are solutions to a prior question asked here on emacs.stackexchange,

- [**How to override major mode bindings?**](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/352/115).

Answer (score 3):

This solution requires installing the [`bind-key`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/bind-key.el) package (available on Melpa and also installed as dependency if you install `use-package`).

The concept of "context-aware" bindings is used here. The below code binds `C-c SPC` to `org-table-blank-field` in the `org-mode-map`; **but only** if `org-at-table-p` returns a non-nil value (i.e. when the point is inside an org table). You can learn more about context-aware bindings from [here](http://endlessparentheses.com/define-context-aware-keys-in-emacs.html).

```el
(bind-keys
 :map org-mode-map
 :filter (org-at-table-p)
  ("C-c SPC" . org-table-blank-field))
```

---

I would even go ahead and bind almost all `org-table` specific bindings using this `:filter` arg:

```el
(bind-keys
 :map org-mode-map
 :filter (org-at-table-p)
  ("C-c ?" . org-table-field-info)
  ("C-c SPC" . org-table-blank-field)
  ("C-c +" . org-table-sum)
  ("C-c =" . org-table-eval-formula)
  ("C-c `" . org-table-edit-field)
  ("C-#" . org-table-rotate-recalc-marks)
  ("C-c }" . org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays)
  ("C-c {" . org-table-toggle-formula-debugger))
```

Comment: This definitely looks cleaner, +1

Answer (score 1):

@kaushalmodi has already mentioned some very good solutions for your problem. I wanted to mention another alternative that I [use](https://github.com/iqbalansari/dotEmacs/blob/master/config/org.org#dwim-binding-for-c-c-spc-in-org-mode).

If you do describe-key for `C-c SPC` in org-mode (<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>), you will notice that it is bound to the command `org-table-blank-field` which is relevant only when you are in org-mode tables, basically useless in most part of an org-mode document.

As such we can define a DWIM command which checks if we are inside an org-mode table, in which case it runs `org-table-blank-field` otherwise it delegates to whatever command <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> is bound to globally and bound that command to <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> in org-mode.

Something like the following should work, if called with a prefix argument it unconditionally delegates to global binding for <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> (`ace-jump-mode` in your case)

```el
(defun my-dwim-org-table-blank-field ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively (if (and (not current-prefix-arg)
                               (org-at-table-p))
                          #'org-table-blank-field
                        (global-key-binding (kbd "C-c SPC")))))

(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (org-defkey org-mode-map (kbd "C-c SPC") #'my-dwim-org-table-blank-field))
```

The macro `with-eval-after-load` was introduced in Emacs v24.4, for older versions use the following form

```el
(eval-after-load "org"
  '(org-defkey org-mode-map (kbd "C-c SPC") #'my-dwim-org-table-blank-field))
```

Comment: I get: `Symbol's function definition is void: with-eval-after-load`

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Seems you are on an Emacs version older than 24.3, updated the answer

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus If you cannot update to the latest emacs version, it might even be helpful to define the `with-eval-after-load` macro locally: http://www.lunaryorn.com/2013/06/25/introducing-with-eval-after-load.html  Personally I prefer using this than the requirement to use quoted form for `eval-after-load`.

Comment: @IqbalAnsari This is a great answer.. I might steal that idea and reimplement using the `:before-until` advice.

Comment: @kaushalmodi Feel free to steal it :)

Comment: @IqbalAnsari [Done!](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/99494f2d974d5e1fbf038343ff391fce04761075/setup-files/setup-org.el#L245-L256) :)

Comment: @kaushalmodi Cool, now I will steal it from your config ;)

Comment: @IqbalAnsari I recently discovered that this creates a buggy behavior when `org-table-blank-field` is called by some other function like `org-table-wrap-region` and if that function is called with a prefix.

Comment: @IqbalAnsari Check out the new approach using context-aware bindings in [my other answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/22457/115).