# Disable C-Tab in magit mode

Tags: key-bindings, magit, keymap

I use C-Tab and C-Shift-Tab to navigate buffer as I would do in a browser. Unfortunately, in magit-mode (which I call using `magit-status`), the key is bound to some diff expansion. The means that I can't switch buffers the ways I would like to as soon as one buffer is in magit-mode. I tried removing the binding using

```
(define-key magit-mode-map
    (kbd "C-<Tab>") nil)
```

However, this does not seem to have any effect. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit:

Regarding my settings: I have a `.emacs.d/buffers.el` which has a line defining the key binding: `(global-set-key [C-tab] 'next-buffer)`.

I am using `use-package` to load magit:

```
(use-package magit
  :ensure t
  :config
  (define-key magit-mode-map (kbd "C-<Tab>") nil)
  (with-eval-after-load 'magit-mode
    (define-key magit-mode-map (kbd "<C-Tab>") nil))
  (setq magit-display-buffer-function
        (lambda (buffer)
          (display-buffer buffer '(display-buffer-same-window)))))
```

I added the suggestion by Konstantin Morenko, but `C-Tab` still does not work properly.

Comment: Works for me. Would you care to add some details about how you set things up?

Comment: This could be helpful: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21978/remove-key-binding-in-magit-status-mode

Comment: Does it work if you use `(kbd "C-<tab>")`? Note the lower case t.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Remove key binding in magit-status-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21978/remove-key-binding-in-magit-status-mode) use in `init.el`

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'magit-mode
  (define-key magit-mode-map (kbd "<C-Tab>") nil))
```

The `(with-eval-after-load FILE &opt BODY)` executes BODY after the FILE is loaded, so, it will rebind keys only after the keybind in `magit-mode` will be created.

**Edit:**

From the documentation of `bind-key.el` from `use-package`

```
;; If you have lots of keybindings set in your .emacs file, it can be hard to
;; know which ones you haven't set yet, and which may now be overriding some
;; new default in a new emacs version.  This module aims to solve that
;; problem.
;;
;; Bind keys as follows in your .emacs:
;;
;;   (require 'bind-key)
;;
;;   (bind-key "C-c x" 'my-ctrl-c-x-command)
;;
;; If you want the keybinding to override all minor modes that may also bind
;; the same key, use the `bind-key*' form:
;;
;;   (bind-key* "<C-return>" 'other-window)
```

So, use in your `buffers.el`

```lisp
(require 'bind-key)
(bind-key "<C-Tab>" 'next-buffer)
```

Comment: Thx, I used `bind-key*` and everything works perfectly.

Comment: It did not work on my setup (Emacs on Windows) until I converted the first letter of "Tab" to lower case: `(kbd "<C-tab>") `