# Binding for (kbd "C-RET") not working

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to setup some keybinds using functions from the `python-x` package. While it works for the simple call `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-j") 'python-shell-send-line)`, when I try to chain multiple functions using the lambda trick I get `<C-return> is undefined` despite having no error at startup. Here is the command I put in the `user-config` in .spacemacs :

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-RET") (lambda () (interactive) (python-shell-send-line) (next-line)))
```

`python-x` works with python mode but the simple keybind is available everywhere while the chained keybinds are all undefined. Where does it go wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(kbd "C-RET")` does not actually refer to "Control return", the way it looks like it will.

To find out how a key should be written, press <kbd>C-h c</kbd> and then the key. If we do that, we get:

```
<C-return> is undefined
```

So, use `C-<return>`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<return>") (lambda () (interactive) (python-shell-send-line) (next-line)))
```

Comment: thanks for the trick that works, I have another problem I'm trying to ovewrite a keybind introduced by `python-x` it's `C-c C-p`, do you know if I can do that in user-config ?

Comment: Check out http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21978/remove-key-binding-in-magit-status-mode . If that doesn't work, ask a separate question, because long answers in comments are hard to read.

Comment: Check out the Emacs [manual section on named ASCII chars](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Named-ASCII-Chars.html) for an explanation of the differences between `RET` and `<return>`.