# "No such file or directory, bind-key" after installing use-package

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows, use-package, error-handling, bind-key.el

I'm using Emacs on Windows 10. I want to override key bindings, so after reading [How to override major mode bindings](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/352), I installed `use-package` with the built-in package manager (via `M-x package-install RET use-package RET`). The package came from the package archive at `http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/`.

When I write `(require 'bind-key)` in my `.emacs` I get the error:

```
File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, bind-key
```

Which makes I can't use the commands `bind-key*`, `bind-keys*` etc. What should I do to be able to use `bind-key`?

Comment: How did you install `use-package`? If you used the built-in package manager `package.el`, e.g. via `M-x package-install RET use-package RET`, then it should have installed `bind-key` along with `use-package`. If you installed `use-package` manually, then you need to install `bind-key` separately as well.

Comment: @Basil I used the built-in package manager. I added that to my question. The value of `package-activated-list` is `(auctex auto-complete popup use-package bind-key)`

Comment: Do you call `(package-initialize)` in your `user-init-file` before trying to `(require 'bind-key)`? Also, why the milkbox URL? Why not `"http(s)://melpa.org/packages/"`?

Comment: @Basil Thank you! With `(package-initialize)` at the first line of my init file, everything works! The URL is one I found at http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html when I was looking for how to install MELPA packages.

Comment: Ah, it looks a bit outdated; I recommend sticking with `melpa.org`.