# Magit: How disable C-<tab>?

Tags: magit

windows 10, emacs 26.1,

I use package `magit` to work with git. 
Nice.

[image]

When I press `C-<tab>` is collapse/expand recent commits:
[image]

Nice. But if I press `<tab>` magit do same thing as when I press `C-<tab>`.
So press `<tab>` and `C-<tab>` do same things.

How I can disable `C-<tab>`. I want to bind `C-<tab>` to another command (no magit command).

Comment: You don't need to disable `C-<tab>`. If you want to bind it to another command, just do that, there's no need to disable it first.

Comment: but note for instance https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/352/how-to-override-major-mode-bindings

Answer (score 4):

`C-<tab>` is bound to `magit-section-cycle` whereas `<tab>` is bound to `magit-section-toggle`. So they are not the same but just happen to do the same in certain (but not all) situations.

If you still want to disable this then the following seems to work

```
(with-eval-after-load 'magit-status
  (define-key magit-status-mode-map (kbd "C-<tab>") nil))
```