# How do I override a key binding defined by `evil-mode`?

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I've searched for this before but I've only seen questions like the below:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs
- [How to override major mode bindings](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/352/how-to-override-major-mode-bindings)

I don't have an understanding of what a major / minor mode really is (which both questions reference) (or whether it's relevant).

---

I'm trying to redefine the `-` key when I'm editing any file. It's currently defined by the evil-mode package in:

**evil-maps.el:**

```
243:(define-key evil-motion-state-map "-" 'evil-previous-line-first-non-blank)
```

How would I go about redefining this to instead run a other function? What are my options - and their implications?

I've managed to what I assume redefines the key binding by adding the following to my `.spacemacs` `user-config`:

```
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map "-" 'deer)
```

Which works, but it feels a bit hacky / cumbersome in case it ever conflicts with a future key binding with another package.

Comment: The question is unclear, to me. You give an example (with `deer`) that you say works, and that looks like it would work (assuming there is a command `deer`). But you still have a question. What's the question, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the General.el, which, as far as I know, was designed to work coherently with evil. Here are the examples for [evil bindings](https://github.com/noctuid/general.el#evil-examples).

This is what might be relevant for you in terms of specifying both evil state and emacs major mode:

```
(general-define-key
 :states ''motion
 :keymaps 'emacs-lisp-mode-map
 "-" 'deer)
```