# Give key binding absolute priority

Tags: key-bindings, elpy, gtk3

I'd like to use `M-<arrows>` to move around windows in Emacs gtk, so I have added

```
(windmove-default-keybindings 'meta)
```

to my `init.el`. However, this is overridden by other modes such as `elpy`. Is there any direct way to give such a command absolute priority on keybindings, ignoring other modes' own keybindings?

Comment: the top answer for https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/352/how-to-override-major-mode-bindings should address your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the mode-specific keybindings explicitly with for example

```
(define-key elpy-mode "M-<left>" nil)
(define-key elpy-mode "M-<right>" nil)
```