# How to change keybinding for all similar functions across all modes?

Tags: key-bindings

Suppose I rebind `C-e` (`move-end-of-line`) to `C-o` in the global-map.

How can I make `C-o` the *corresponding* function in all modes (if it exists).

So, for example, in org-mode `C-o` should be `org-end-of-line`, not `move-end-of-line`.

NB: I do not simply want, in this example, `C-o` to be `move-end-of-line` everywhere. Rather I want it to be the corresponding command for that mode, which in this case is `org-end-of-line`.

Comment: I do not know if there is an "emacs.stackexchange.com" answer, but there are some answers on stackoverflow with the Emacs tag:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs  In addition to the answers in that linked thread, I've seen at least one other variation of an answer by @phils that provides a minor-mode definition ... [I didn't see it in my limited Google search today, but have seen it in the past.]

Comment: @lawlist: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs/5340797#5340797)?

Comment: @NickD -- thanks for looking for additional threads where *phils* has posted some solutions.  The link you cited is one of the multiple answers to the same thread that I linked in the comment above yours.  I just did some more Googling and can't seem to find the thread I remembered reading ... probably on stackoverflow from a few years ago.

Comment: Yes, sorry - I looked after I posted and it did not conform to your description.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override major mode bindings](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/352/how-to-override-major-mode-bindings)

Comment: It doesn't seem to. If I use `bind-keys*` the other modes do not seem to be affected.

Comment: Note that all `bind-keys*` does is make sure that the keybinding is not overridden. That is not what I am asking. See the question for full info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how, in each major mode, to bind to `C-o` whatever that mode normally binds to `C-e`?

If so, then in `after-change-major-mode-hook` add a function such as this:

```lisp
(defun my-remap-C-e-to-C-o ()
  "Remap whatever command is locally bound to `C-e` to `C-o`."
  (let* ((map       (current-local-map))
         (C-e-bind  (lookup-key map (kbd "C-e") t)))
    (define-key map (kbd "C-o") (or C-e-bind  'move-end-of-line))))

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook #'my-remap-C-e-to-C-o)
```

If the local mode does not, itself, bind `C-e` then the `C-o` gets bound, in that mode, to `move-end-of-line`.

This code does not remove the global binding of `C-e`.  If you also want to do that then:

```lisp
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-e"))
```

Comment: Yep. You understand my question.