# How to redefine prefix key in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, prefix-keys

I have rebound C-u to another function, and try to use C-j for the prefix, but now it seems I cannot use the prefix in org-mode. It does seem to work in other modes though.

```
; This is the relevant part of my current config (I think)
(global-set-key "\C-j" 'universal-argument)
(define-key universal-argument-map "\C-j" 'universal-argument-more)
(define-key universal-argument-map "\C-u" nil)
(define-key global-map "\C-u" nil)

(use-package org
  :bind
  (:map org-mode-map
        ("C-e" . next-line))
  )
```

How can I make C-j the prefix in org-mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work for any mode that **doesn't** bind `C-j` for some purpose. `orgmode` binds `C-j` to `org-return-indent` in the org-mode keymap. The major-mode keymap takes precedence over the global keymap, so your modifications have no effect.

To make this work in org-mode, you'll need to bind `C-j` specifically in the orgmode keymap:

```
(define-key org-mode-map "\C-j" 'universal-argument)
```

You will run into the same problem in any mode that uses `C-j` for something. You might find some useful ideas in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/352/how-to-override-major-mode-bindings).