# How to override org-mode-map key bindings?

Tags: key-bindings

I would like to override the `C-c C-j` keybinding.
I put this in my init file

```
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-j") 'counsel-org-goto)
```

However, it won't override the command `org-goto` (found in org-mode-map).

Thanks for your input!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override major mode bindings](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/352/how-to-override-major-mode-bindings)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this expression:

```el
(with-eval-after-load "org"
  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-j") #'counsel-org-goto))
```

The Org mode keymap "shadows" the global map. In Emacs, the keymaps of major modes take precedence over keybindings in the global keymap.

See this excellent tutorial from Mickey Petersen for a thorough discussion of the "keymap lookup order": https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs.

Comment: Thanks Phil, that's better.

Comment: This worked like a charm! I understand the logic. Thanks so much.